# url rewrite outbound iis express 8.0 error

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-express, outbound

I been following example  from http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module

What i have try is 
1. removed all gzip code.
2. add some registry as some website said so but mostly for iis7.
http://www.deherrera.org/Blog/Post/23/IIS7-Dynamic-Compression-%E2%80%93-HTTP-Error-500-52

Error Code : HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.

```
<system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to clean URL">
      <match filterByTags="A" pattern="^Ads\.aspx\?id=([0-9]+)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="/Ads/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
 </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Some error message at tracelog folder

```
<failedRequest 
  url="http://localhost:2379/"
  siteId="2063751106"
  appPoolId="Clr4IntegratedAppPool"
  processId="6284"
  verb="GET"
  remoteUserName=""
  userName=""
  tokenUserName="alien3d-PC\alien3d"
  authenticationType="anonymous"
  activityId="{00000000-0000-0000-2A00-0080000000F5}"
  failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
  statusCode="200"
  triggerStatusCode="500.52"
  timeTaken="2013"
  xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb">
```

Comment: Seem It work on normal IIS windows 7 but not work on IIS express 8 and azure website

Comment: work on iis express 8 and normal iis .. azure seem not working :(

Comment: update.. seem azure required connection string update in the portal instead of using web.config.. weird

Comment: can you elaborate more how you solve it? I have the same issue!